# Math.round not returning integers as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to edit an existing (working, shown first) script that delivers two decimals so that it will only deliver rounded numbers - my edit shown second ([example](http://www.fabulousyarn.com/malabrigo-rasta-frankochre.shtml)). To be clear I want simple integers i.e. 18 not 18.00.

```
function D(r){
    if (r.stat === "ok") {
        for (var k in r.items) {
            document.write(r.items[k].inventory)
        }
    }
}

function D(r){
    if (r.stat === "ok") {
        for (var k in r.items) {
            document.write(r.items[k].inventory)
            Math.round()
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What result were you expecting from calling `Math.round` with no arguments?

Comment: Why would just throwing `Math.round()` in there with no arguments and without returning the result anywhere do anything at all? Maybe you should just read the [**docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) for whatever method you're trying to use, and look at the examples.

Answer (score 5):

You can try one of these methods to do that according to your requirements:

- **Math.floor()**

  `intvalue = Math.floor( floatvalue );`
- **Math.ceil()**

  `intvalue = Math.ceil( floatvalue );`
- **Math.round()**

  `intvalue = Math.round( floatvalue );`

Example:

```
value = 3.65

Math.ceil(value); // 4

Math.floor(value); // 3

Math.round(value); // 4
```

in your function :

you should pass argument to method `math.round` to work as expected :

```
Math.round(r.items[k].inventory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.round works just fine. Put the thing you want rounded in between the parentheses `()`.

```js
let foo = {
  stat: "ok",
  items: {
    apple: {
      inventory: 18.45
    }
  }
}

function D(r) {
  if (r.stat === "ok") {
    for (var k in r.items) {
      console.log(Math.round(r.items[k].inventory))
    }
  }
}

D(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rounding numbers.

There are many ways to round a number each with slight differences.

#### To closest integer

Generally you round to the closest whole number

```
Math.round(9.4) == 9; // is true
Math.round(9.6) == 10; // is true

Math.round(-9.4) == -9; // is true
Math.round(-9.6) == -10; // is true
```

#### Midway point round up

In the case where you are halfway you round up towards Infinity

```
Math.round(9.5) == 10; // is true
Math.round(-9.5) == 9; // is true
```

You **do not** round to the nearest even

```
 Math.round(8.5) == 9; // is true
 Math.round(-7.5) == -7; // is true
```

#### Midway point round away from zero

If you want to round the mid point away from 0 you can use

```
 9.5.toFixed() == 10; // is true
-9.5.toFixed() == -10; // is true
```

Note the result is a string so if you want a number convert it as follows

```
Number( 9.5.toFixed()) === 10; // is true
Number(-9.5.toFixed()) === -10; // is true
```

#### Midway point round to even

If you wish to round to the nearest even you will have to create a function

```
const roundEven = (val) => {
    if (Math.abs(val % 1) === 0.5) {
        return (val = Math.round(val), val - (val % 2) * Math.sign(val));
    }
    return Math.round(val);
}


roundEven(9.5) === 10; // is true
roundEven(-9.5) === -10; // is true
roundEven(8.5) === 8; // is true
roundEven(-8.5) === -8; // is true
```

#### Example

```js
show("Math.round(9.4) === " + Math.round(9.4))
show("Math.round(9.6) === " + Math.round(9.6))

show("Math.round(-9.4) === " + Math.round(-9.4))
show("Math.round(-9.6) === " + Math.round(-9.6))

show("Math.round(9.5) === " + Math.round(9.5) )
show("Math.round(-9.5) === " + Math.round(-9.5) )


show("Math.round(8.5) === " + Math.round(8.5) )
show("Math.round(-7.5) === " + Math.round(-7.5) )

show(" 9.5.toFixed() === '" + 9.5.toFixed() + "'" )
show("-9.5.toFixed() === '" + -9.5.toFixed() + "'" )
   
show("Number( 9.5.toFixed()) === " + Number(9.5.toFixed()))
show("Number(-9.5.toFixed()) === " + Number(-9.5.toFixed()))


const roundEven = (val) => {
if (Math.abs(val % 1) === 0.5) {
    return (val = Math.round(val), val - (val % 2) * Math.sign(val));
}
return Math.round(val);
}

show("roundEven(9.5) === " + roundEven(9.5))
show("roundEven(-9.5) === " + roundEven(-9.5))
show("roundEven(8.5) === " + roundEven(8.5))
show("roundEven(-8.5) === " + roundEven(-8.5))
show("roundEven(0.5) === " + roundEven(0.5))
show("roundEven(-0.5) === " + roundEven(-0.5))



function show(text){
   const d = document.createElement("div");
   d.textContent = text;
   document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```